# Complexity of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

```
Input: p > 2, a; 1 < a < p 
Output: Boolean: if p is a probable prime
    b = a**(p-1)
    if (b % p == 1){ return true; }
    else { return false; }
```

So I'm thinking that the multiplication for `b` is `log₂(a) * log₂(p-1)`, then the mod check is `log₂(b)`?

Answer (score 1):

`b = a ** (p-1)` means `ap-1`.

The complexity depends on the implementation of the exponentiation. In most cases I know, the simple `power` works by multiplying the basis with it's self as often as required. This results in something like `O(log₂(a)⋅p)`.

But if you use an implementation of the [fast exponentiation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Basic_method), you get indeed `O(log₂(p)⋅log₂(p)) = O((log₂(p))²)`, since you can use modulo `p` after each step and so your resulting numbers never get bigger than `p`.

Notice: The function returns `true` if `p` is prime or `p` is an [Carmichael number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_number).

Comment: Thank you! I am aware of Carmichael numbers, I'm actually writing a paper which includes this vulnerability.